# Fisher Information, on discrete uniform distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution, fisher-information

suppose that I have a sample with n observations $X_1,X_2...X_n$ that each follows **discrete** uniform distribution $DU(1,\theta)$, where the smallest possible value is 1, and the largest is n. So the probability function is $1/\theta$.

And my question is, what is the fisher information for parameter "$\theta$".

And what is Jeffreys prior for it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the largest possible value is $\theta$?

Comment: yeah! sorry i changed n into $\theta$ in the last min and i miss one "n" in the sentence ..." and the largest is n". So the largest possible value is $\theta$, (we usually denote parameter of interest as $\theta$).

Comment: Fisher information is not defined for distributions with support depending on parameter.